# WC_get_products Meta Query being ignored

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, meta-query

Im having problems with **wc_get_products** meta query. Im trying to exclude products that have `clearance` or `express` in the SKU and the SKUs are formatted like so; (not my choice something the company decided many moons ago!)

My Club - Express - Item
My Club - Clearance - Item
Another Club - Standard - Item

Below are my args, please could someone tell me what's wrong with them?

```
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'future', 'private'),
    'parent' => array( 13, 14, 15 ),
    'limit' => 1000,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order'   => 'asc',
    'type' => array( 'simple', 'variable' ),
    'meta_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'and',
                        array(
                            'relation'  => 'or',
                                array(
                                'key' => '_sku',
                                'value' => 'clearance',
                                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                                ),
                            ),
                        array(
                            'relation' => 'or',
                                array(
                                'key' => '_sku',
                                'value' => 'fxpe',
                                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                                ),
                            ),
                        )
);
```

I have also completed the woocommerce steps (at bottom of page) [Adding Custom Parameter Support](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) which looks like this:

```
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['_sku'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => '_sku',
            'value' => esc_attr( $query_vars['_sku'] ),
        );
    }

    return $query;
 }

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
```

I've also tried reversing the meta query and changing the compare to `like` or `!=` but nothing works or seems to affect the query.

Any help really appreciate.

Thanks

***UPDATE-------------------------------***

I made a major typo in the initial post, to confirm I am using **wc_get_products no wp_query**

I have been trying a few variations of the meta query but so far nothing is working...

Just using a single meta query doesn't seem to work either

```
'meta_query' => array(
                        'key' => '_sku',
                        'value' => 'express',
                        'compare' => '!=',  // also tried 'NOT LIKE'

                        ),
```

Becuase of the inital confusion with the query I will mark Howard E's question correct as it is for wp_query and repost witht he correct information.

Comment: Does your query provide expected results when you drop the meta query?

Comment: the correct results are returned but they include products with the 'express' and 'clearance' sku's. and yes if the meta query is removed everything works as normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating your meta_query.  You're starting by saying "OR" for the relation of both `clearance` and `express` also.

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
            'key' => '_sku',
            'value' => 'clearance',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
            'key' => '_sku',
            'value' => 'express',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    )
```

*** To deal with Updated Question ***

```
function handle_custom_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['_sku'] ) ) {
        $query['meta_query'][] =  array(
        array(
                'relation'  => 'or',
                    array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => 'fxpe',
                    'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'or',
                    array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => 'clearance',
                    'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
            );
    }

    return $query;
 }
```

Then just use `_sku` in the product query with a value...

```
$products = wc_get_products(array(
     'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'future', 'private'),
    'parent' => array( 13, 14, 15 ),
    'limit' => 1000,
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'order'   => 'asc',
    'type' => array( 'simple', 'variable' ),
    '_sku' => true,
));
```

adding this filter will however filter any instance of `_sku` in the WC query.  You may want to add additional conditionals if needed.

Comment: Sorry i spoke too soon! the query is still ignoring the meta query. all results are loading including what i want excluded...

Comment: What are these SKU's like?

Comment: all characters eg. "My Club - Category - Item", not the best i know but due to the powers at be it must be like this

Comment: ive also tried stripping it down to just one meta query which doesnt seem to work either, all results returned including the excluded ones.

Comment: did you try changing both relations to "And"?

Comment: I have tried what you said and it made no difference but I've made a stupid error in calling this a wp_query when in fact its a wc_get_products query which does affect the meta query. I have updated the post with all the info if you're interested in taking a look? Thanks

Comment: Look at the bottom of this page: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query `$products = wc_get_products( array( 'customvar' => 'somevalue' ) );`  You are not using `meta_query` in yorur `wc_get_products`