# wc_get_products with two meta_query condition being ignored

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I'm tryng to do a wc_get_products with two meta_query conditions, but it doesn't work. It returns random results and I don't know why (When I refresh the page the products given change)

The code that I'm using is:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => $itemsperpage,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'relation'  => 'AND',
                    array(
                    'key' => '_iop',
                    'value' => '2',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    ),
                ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                    'key' => '_iop',
                    'value' => '6',
                    'compare' => '=',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
            'order'     => 'ASC'
        ); 

$products = wc_get_products($args);
```

I want to show results which meta key _iop is 2 or 6, but doesn't work. ¿Where is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues with this query:

1. There is no inner `relation` for the inner array of the `meta_query`.
2. You don't need both inner arrays, since it can be a single array for your value.
3. You don't need your outer `'relation' => 'AND'`, since it's now a single inner array.
4. `wc_get_products` does not accept the normal query args - so you will need to use `get_posts` or create a new `WP_Query( $args )`.

If you must use the `wc_get_products`, check this out: [WC_get_products Meta Query being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168358/wc-get-products-meta-query-being-ignored)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $itemsperpage,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array (
        array(
            'key' => '_iop',
            'value' => array(2,6),
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    ),
    'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
);

$products = new WP_Query($args);
```